# Multiple citation standard

Tags: citations

We know that there are standards that if some site implements them it will be compatible with zotero.

Is there any standard for multiple scrapping?
Which standard should be implemented by site developers in search result page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-posted from the Zotero forum:
unAPI (preferred) and COinS both work with multiple items.
The other methods don't work for search results.

As an example for unAPI see e.g. inSpire:
http://inspirehep.net/search?p=citedby%3Aauthor%3Aellis+-refersto%3Aauthor%3Awitten

An example for COinS on search pages there's e.g. Harvard's new Hollis catalog:
http://hollis.harvard.edu/